# Using Read and Publish permissions in facebook sdk 4.6.0

Tags: android, facebook

So I am playing with facebook api and i want to set publish permission while having read permission so i wrote the following lines which perform this task:

```
login = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    login.setReadPermissions("email", "user_likes", "user_friends","user_status","user_posts");
    login.setPublishPermissions("publish_pages");
```

Now, when i run the code i get this exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.reminder.qwer.reminder1/com.reminder.qwer.reminder1.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot call setPublishPermissions after setReadPermissions has been called.
```

I saw that in older versions there was a method called setPermissions which was used for setting read and publish permissions in same time. My question is:  Do i have to recreate the AccesToken with the publish permissions or there is another way?

Answer (score 4):

This behavior is by design and [documented](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginButton/#setReadPermissions), too:

> Set the permissions to use when the user logs in. The permissions here
>   can only be read permissions. If any publish permissions are included,
>   the login attempt by the user will fail. The LoginButton can only be
>   associated with either read permissions or publish permissions, but
>   not both. Calling both setReadPermissions and setPublishPermissions on
>   the same instance of LoginButton will result in an exception being
>   thrown unless clearPermissions is called in between.

If you want the user to also grant your app publish permissions, you'll have to invoke the login dialog again. You can do this using the [`LoginManager`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginManager/).

Answer (score 0):

`Set read permissions` and `set publish permissions` can't be used
at the same time. You can either use any one of them. It's better if
you declare set publish permissions in another activity and use
intents to call the activity with set publish permissions.

```
@Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
      //this loginManager helps you eliminate adding a LoginButton to your UI
        loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
        loginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);
        loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
            {
                //write your code here
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {}

        });}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a solution, following the tutorial, you must set just one type of permission in your button, and make sure of do it just like this example:

```
loginButtonFacebook.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("permission1, permission2"));
```

Then, on your onSucces method, call the method:

`LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(context, Arrays.asList("permissionA, permissionB"));`

just like this:

```
@Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        final AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(context, Arrays.asList("rsvp_event"));
        //Do something else
    }
```

In this way, after user's authentication, the api will ask him for read permissions and after accept them, it will ask for publish permissions.

Comment: I tried this but on second login (with Publish permission) it jumps to onCanceled. Do you know why?

Comment: Hi, mmm that's weird, did you make sure removing all app permissions from facebook configuration before try again?